# Get non duplicates of column x but duplicates of column y

Tags: sql, join, unique, record

I have a table (call it table myTable).

It has the data like this:

number /   name

```
1    jake
2    chris
3    sally
4    billy
1    tom
5    cathy
```

(I realize this is a poor setup, but I didn't get the luxury of doing the setup)

---

---

I need to query this table so that the results are returned with:

```
1    jake
2    chris
3    sally
4    billy
5    cathy
```

OR

```
2    chris
3    sally
4    billy
1    tom
5    cathy
```

---

---

It does not matter which name gets returned for the duplicated number... only that ONE gets returned.

Here is my not-working attempt:

```
with
a as (
      SELECT number
      FROM myTable
),

b as (
      SELECT number, name
      FROM myTable
)


SELECT a."number", b."name"

FROM a
left join b on a."number" = b."number"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` to ensure that each `number` is only returned once, and use an aggregate function to pick one of the values for `name`:

```
SELECT number, MAX(name) AS name
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY number
```

Comment: rofl rofl. MAX function, didnt think to use that on a string! thanks!! i'll mark this as the answer in 9 minutes when its allowed.  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since you don't care which of the multiple names belonging to a number are returned, you can use a max or min function.

```
select number, max(name)
from myTable
group by number
```